# A simple way to create three struct linked lists

Tags: c, struct

I would like to create a linkage list of three structures in total.
Is there any way to make the code below simpler?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct hello {
    int data;
    struct hello *next;
};

void main()
{
    struct hello *head;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct hello));
        head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct hello));
        head->next->next = malloc(sizeof(struct hello));
        head->next->next->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bad assumption in your code: That the pointer `head` would be initialized to be a null pointer. It's not. The value of `head` without explicit initialization is *indeterminate*, and will seem almost random (and most likely not `NULL`).

Comment: By the way, is this some kind of homework exercise? Because otherwise it would make no sense in making a limited list like this, instead of making generic functions to add and remove nodes from any list.. The code you have (minus the `head == NULL` check) is the simplest way to create such a (short!) list. One more and a loop would definitely be better, especially since you don't seem to be caring about order of nodes or their `data`.

Comment: Well, yes, you can quite simply declare an *array of struct* and then simply wire the pointer for the next element added until you fill your array. Here, you have used storage for an array on the stack, instead of creating storage with `malloc` from the heap, but other than that, the basic list operations are exactly the same. Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most basic and easier to understand, and *simpler* solution to start with would be taking an array of pointers and looping.

The other issue with your code that I could observe is:

```
struct hello *head;

    if (head == NULL) { }
```

`head` is local variable of a pointer type, its not guaranteed to be initialized to zero unless your code does that.

In the code below, `pNode` will do that for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct hello {
    int data;
    struct hello *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    struct hello *pNode[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL };

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pNode[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct hello));
        if(pNode[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("No memory");
            // Some error-handling
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // lets link all the nodes that were malloc'ed (successfully)
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) //Note: loop from index 0 to 1, instead of 2.
    {
        pNode[i]->next = pNode[i+1];
    }       
    pNode[2]->next = NULL;

    // Ugly, straight, crude way to write data values
    pNode[0]->data = 10;
    printf("\n%d", pNode[0]->data);
    pNode[0]->next->data = 20;
    printf("\n%d, %d", pNode[0]->next->data, pNode[1]->data);
    pNode[0]->next->next->data = 30;
    printf("\n%d, %d", pNode[0]->next->next->data, pNode[2]->data);

    return 0;
}
```

Make sure that you make a habit of checking if the malloc returned anything, otherwise you need to handle that error as well.

Remember, the code above can always be implemented in far more optimized, intelligent and sophisticated ways. Its just that I wanted to throw up a basic code which seems to do what it says, and something that you can always go and change as and when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to add any more nodes(structures), even if it meant taking one out of the list and putting it back in again, then you could make it even shorter (if short is what you mean by simple) by removing the

```
if(head==null)
```

if statement. It would be null (most probably rubbish value) in the beginning anyway.

However, implementation of linked lists in this manner is not recommended. It lacks scalability (in which I mean, if you had to increase the number of nodes later on it would be tedious) and makes it harder - almost impossible in this case - to make changes later on.

There are tons of linked list examples on the internet. A few good habits would be to include an add_node function, a delete_node function, and a search_node function. Just by adding these functions to your linked list, your code would become much more manageable.

If it doesn't have to be a linked list, an int[3] array would do just fine as well.

Hope this helped.

Comment: oh, the "head->next->next->next = NULL;" wouldn't be necessary as well, if the total number of nodes are to be fixed as 3.